# Dynamics 365 - why the older version of PCF grid component is running after installing new one?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps

I create a PCF grid component into a power app (Dynamics 365).
After installing a newer version of PCF into the power app, I still see the behavior and appearance of the old version.

It does not help to change the version, change the name or uninstall the solution with PCF, in the form PCF is still offered even after uninstallation.

Where is the problem?

Comment: did you try clearing the browser cache?

Comment: I tried almost everything. Even I cleared all the caches I found.
But I forgot, that deleting of the unmanaged solution did not delete its components. So I explicitly delete the PCF component and now new PCF version is working.  It is some kind of workaround and standard PCF update still not working.